# Is it possible to share 3rd party API websocket/realtime connection through GraphQL/REST backend?

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket, graphql, server-sent-events

My backend server connects to a third party API service. This third party API service sends events via a websocket to my backend, which then relays back to my frontend. Every message sent from the websocket, I pay for.

In addition, the websocket provides different data depending on which value is requested. An example: Imagine an API service that provides real-time payments for different products. If I want to receive real-time payments for books, I'd use the value "books". And if I'd want to receive real-time payments for iPhones, I'd use the value "iPhones", etc.

To minimise cost spend, I'd preferably want users connecting through my backend to share the stream of information, rather than creating a new websocket connection every time. And for connections that are not in use, to be disconnected from the third party websocket. I.e. If a user were to request "book"s through my backend, a connection would be opened to the third party API & then subsequently streamed back. If another user were to also request "book"s they'd just hop onto the existing opened connection.

Is this a possibility with GraphQL & how'd would you imagine this being implemented? Just off the top of my head, I'd imagine some sort of tracking on the backend side which checks what connections are opened & whether they're being used. Otherwise, is it possible in REST?

Comment: It sounds like *extra effort* to make a websocket every time, instead of just once. The default would imho be to make 1 connection... why do you make so many in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something very similar with Apollo's polling features with a little custom logic thrown in.

Basically, you could open a connection to the third-party using polling as a socket to update the data layer. Then, when another user queries that data layer, it should already exist (or you can add a quick check on top of that).